# React native chrome debugger not showing that console.log and default logs

Tags: react-native, debugging

i recently upgraded from RN 0.61.5 to 0.62.2.
However, chrome debugger won't work from some point on. This means that the debugger and simulator are well connected, but I don't see any of the basic logs that I use `console.log`, or that first pops up logs.

So, i try some solutions.
first, I reset the project. and run `react-native init <my-project>`. and copy & paste past source code(Except for system files or node_modules) that src, .gitignore etc
but, this situations keep goes on now.

second, git revert when it worked well before upgrade.
but this is same bad result like above. everything is good. project's Run or Build ···. 
ONLY NOT WORKING debugger..

what should i do ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

[Please look this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Ml2.png)

Answer (score 2):

SELF ANSWER

One of the Babel packages I'm using, the `Babel-plugin-transform-remove-console`, had eliminated all the logs even in development mode.

If you remove this from the project, it works normally.